# Flutter clippath usage

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make an image comparison widget, here is a sample image. I tried with clippath but I couldn't, it's not fully proportioned. How can I get the image below?

[image]

```
Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: genislik / 2,
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: Custom2(),
                  child: Image.network(
                    oncesi,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 300,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: genislik / 2,
                  child: ClipPath(
                    clipper: Custom(),
                    child: Image.network(
                      sonrasi,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 300,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              /* Center(
                child: Image.network(
                  araCizgi,
                  height: 300,
                ),
              ),*/
            ],
          )
```